# jquery last tweet time ago

Tags: jquery, twitter, time

I have a script that allows to display the last tweet.

I success to display tweet text, url, username and tweet time.

However, I want to transform the tweet time in time ago.

Here my script:

```
function parseDate(str) {
    var v=str.split(' ');
    return new Date(Date.parse(v[1]+" "+v[2]+", "+v[5]+" "+v[3]+" UTC"));
} 

function loadLatestTweet(){
var _url = "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/"+tweeteraccount+".json?callback=?&count=1";
$.getJSON(_url,function(data){
    var tweet = data[0].text;
            var created = parseDate(data[0].created_at);
            var createdDate = created.getDate()+'/'+(created.getMonth()+1)+'/'+created.getFullYear()+', '+created.getHours()+':'+created.getMinutes();
            tweet = tweet.parseURL().parseUsername().parseHashtag();
    tweet += '<br><div id="twitter-date">'+createdDate+'</div>'
    $("#twitter").html(tweet);
    });
}
```

I found a script that allows to convert time in time ago but I don't know how to add it to my script. How to integrate the relative_time script to my parseDate script

Here the script for time ago conversion:

```
function relative_time(time_value) {
    var values =time_value.split(" ");
    time_value =values[1] + " " + values[2]+ ", " + values[5] +" "+ values[3];
    var parsed_date = Date.parse(time_value);
    var relative_to = (arguments.length> 1)? arguments[1] :newDate();
    var delta =parseInt((relative_to.getTime()- parsed_date) /1000);
    delta = delta + (relative_to.getTimezoneOffset()* 60);
    var r = '';
    if (delta <60) {
        r = 'aminute ago';
    } else if(delta < 120) {
        r = 'couple of minutes ago';
    } else if(delta < (45*60)) {
        r = (parseInt(delta / 60)).toString()+ ' minutes ago';
    } else if(delta < (90*60)) {
        r = 'an hourago';
    } else if(delta < (24*60*60)) {
        r = ''+ (parseInt(delta / 3600)).toString() +' hoursago';
    } else if(delta < (48*60*60)) {
        r = '1day ago';
    } else {
        r = (parseInt(delta / 86400)).toString() +' days ago';
    }
    return r;
}
```

Sorry for my English, I'm French

Comment: check http://timeago.yarp.com/

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I don't want a dedicated script just for convert time in time ago. Just the if condition is enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here what I use for tweets time

```
// Convert the tweet creation date/time to Twitter format
// This eliminates annoying server vs. browser time zone differences
function twitter_time($time) {
    $delta = time() - strtotime($time);
    if ($delta < 60) {
        return 'less than a minute ago';
    } else if ($delta < 120) {
        return 'about a minute ago';
    } else if ($delta < (45 * 60)) {
        return floor($delta / 60) . ' minutes ago';
    } else if ($delta < (90 * 60)) {
        return 'about an hour ago.';
    } else if ($delta < (24 * 60 * 60)) {
        return floor($delta / 3600) . ' hours ago';
    } else if ($delta < (48 * 60 * 60)) {
        return '1 day ago';
    } else {
        return floor($delta / 86400) . ' days ago';
    }
}
```